# How to create a new primary key in Entity Framework, Database first?

Tags: entity-framework

I get a runtime exception from the below code.  I think it is not creating a primary key (which is CustomerID, and int).  I used the Wizard and I have experience from years ago with ADO.NET but this is my first project using Entity Framework 6.0 with DbContext.  I generated the EDMX file using "database first", so an actual database is present.  I don't *think* any other table has a foreign key association with this table that is mandatory, so I think (but am not sure) this runtime error is from a failure to create new primary key.  This is either a very easy question or a hard one, so I will check later.

Paul

```
[OperationContract]
public void DoWork ()
{
     try
     {
            using (var ctx = new MyEDMXdBExistingDatabase())
            {
                CUSTOMER myCustomerREALLYNEW = new CUSTOMER();
                myCustomerREALLYNEW.LastName = "NeWLASTNAME";

                myCustomerREALLYNEW.CustomerID = 0; //set primary key to zero and let entity framework create new one automagically?  I think this works based on past experience, but it's not working now  

                ctx.CUSTOMERs.Add(myCustomerREALLYNEW);
                ctx.SaveChanges(); //PROBLEM HERE If comment out this line no runtime error
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex1)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex1.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
        } 
}
```

Comment: Which exception do you receive when you create a customer ? post exception detail.

Comment: Thank you Mohsen Esmailpour.  You win the bonus.  In fact, it turns out there is a required non-null field that needed to be filled. Once I did that, the problem went away.  I'll edit my question in case this question is not deleted by the moderator.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code and it showed me that the new CUSTOMER was lacking a manditory, non-null field (the Address).  Once I added myCustomerREALLYNEW.Address= "123 Street";  then the new record/object could be added.

Here is the code I added to catch the runtime exception, which I got off the net:

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex1)
{
Debug.WriteLine("!" + ex1.Message);
List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
foreach (DbEntityValidationResult validationResult in ex1.EntityValidationErrors)
{
string entityName = validationResult.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
foreach (DbValidationError error in validationResult.ValidationErrors)
{
errorMessages.Add(entityName + "." + error.PropertyName + ":" + errorMessages);
}
}

foreach (string s in errorMessages)
{
Debug.WriteLine(s);
}

}
```